# Redux - Async-Await response undefined but 'works'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm in the middle of learning redux and I don't understand why ****response** returns undefined**.

But at the same time when I look in the developer tools -> network I can see that I **successfully fetched the data** I want.

```
import { onSearchSubmit } from "../apis/unsplash";

export const searchTerm = (term) => async (dispatch) => {
    const response = await onSearchSubmit(term);
    
    dispatch({ type: "SEARCH_TERM", payload: response });
};
```

```
import axios from "axios";

export const onSearchSubmit = (term) => {
    axios.get("https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos", {
        params: { query: term },
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Client-ID API_KEY",
        },
    });
};
```

Comment: Try `console.log(response);`.

Comment: maybe `onSearchSubmit` isn't returning anything but has the code to fetch

Comment: What does `onSearchSubmit` look like?

Comment: It's returning `undefined` because you're not returning anything - `return axios.get`.

Comment: Thank you return axios.get solved the problem